# What is the quotient $\mathbb{T}^3/\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, general-topology, k-theory

What is the quotient space $\mathbb{T}^3/\mathbb{Z}_2$, When  $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acting on 3-dimensional torus   $\mathbb{T}^3 := \mathbb{R}^3/\mathbb{Z}^3$ by sending $x$ to $-x$? Does anyone know how to compute its K-theory or cohomology groups?

Comment: Cohomology groups should be fairly easy, given time and patience: after all, there is an obvious invariant cell decomposition. Did you try it?

Comment: This is the wrong forum for your question. I've voted to re-direct to MSE.

Comment: The quotient is homeomorphic to $T^3$.  Sketch:  Consider $T^3$ as a Lie group.  Then $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{\pm (1,1,1)\}$ is a subgroup and your action is nothing but multiplication by the nontrivial element.  Then $T^3/\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a quotient of an abelian Lie group by a normal subgroup, so is itself an abelian Lie group.  Since it's also compact, it must be Lie isomorphic to $T^3$.  I don't have time to flesh this out into a longer answer....

Comment: And, yet-again, $\mathbb Z_2$ will be read as "$2$-adic integers" by most mathematicians...

Comment: @JasonDeVito I'm not sure that the action of $\Bbb Z/2$ stated is the action of a subgroup.

Comment: @Tyler:  Could you (or someone else) elaborate?  I'm not following:  If $x\in T^3$, then $x = (p_1, p_2, p_3)$, and $(-1,-1,-1)\cdot (p_1, p_2, p_3) = (-p_1, -p_2, -p_3) = -(p_1, p_2,p_3) = -x$.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Jason: The Lie group structure on $T^3$ in the question, viewed as $\Bbb R^3 / \Bbb Z^3$, is $(a,b,c)\cdot(d,e,f) = (a+d,b+e,c+f)$. You're probably using the identification $T^3 = (S^1)^3$, where $S^1$ is viewed as a subset of the complex numbers; the same formula gives you a different action there.

Comment: @Tyler:  Got it!    So, in my notation, the action would be $(p_1, p_2, p_3)\mapsto (\overline{p_1}, \overline{p_2}, \overline{p_3})$.  This is indeed a much more interesting problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's construct cell structures on $X_n=\mathbb{T}^n/\{\pm1\}$ by induction on $n$.  To do this, consider $X_n$ as a quotient of $Y_n=[-1/2,1/2]^n\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, and consider the following cell structure on $Y_n$ defined by induction on $n$: for each closed cell $A$ in the standard cell structure on the cube $[-1/2,1/2]^{n-1}$, let $[-1/2,0]\times A$ and $[0,1/2]\times A$ be closed cells of $Y_n$.  For each closed cell $A$ in our cell structure on $Y_{n-1}$, let $\{x\}\times A$ be a closed cell of $Y_n$ for $x=-1/2$, $x=0$, and $x=1/2$.  It is straightforward to verify that this indeed defines a cell structure on $Y_n$, and that it descends to a cell structure on the quotient $X_n$.  Furthermore, we can see from this construction that the 1-skeleton of $X_n$ consists of two copies of the 1-skeleton of $X_{n-1}$ joined by an edge.  By induction, this implies the 1-skeleton of $X_n$ is contractible for all $n$.

Now set $n=3$; it can be checked that our cell structure on $X_3$ has a single $3$-cell and four $2$-cells.  Furthermore, the boundary of the 3-cell can be computed to be of the form $2a-2b$, where $a$ and $b$ are two of the $2$-cells. Since the 1-skeleton of $X_3$ is contractible, we can reduce it to a point without changing the homotopy type.  It follows that the only nontrivial reduced homology group of $X_3$ is $H_2(X_3)=\mathbb{Z}^3\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$, and so $X_3$ is a Moore space $M(\mathbb{Z}^3\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2,2)$.

(I recommend you draw pictures of these cell structures for $n\leq 3$ to verify my claims; you can also see easily that $X_2\cong S^2$.)

Comment: Do you have any idea how to explicitly compute K-theory for this space?  The thing I want to know if there is torsion in K-theory or not. I am trying to use Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence.

Comment: The Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence degenerates because the only nontrivial reduced cohomology is in two adjacent degrees.  You get $K^0(X_3)=\mathbb{Z}^4$ and $K^1(X_3)=\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: very nice, and the K-homology would be $K_0(X_3) = \mathbb{Z}^4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 $ and $K_1(X_3) = 0$. right?